# Select part of array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I tried select and write part of arrays. But my code select `char` of array .

There is my source coce:

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
      <table border = "1" >
         <tr>
            <th>All Arrays</th>
            <th>Selected Array</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><p id="TotalArray"></p></td>
            <td><p id="SelectedId"></p></td>
        </tr>
  </table>

      <table border = "1" >
         <tr>
            <th>PartOne</th>
            <th>PartTwo</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><p id="PartOneItem"></p></td>
            <td><p id="PartTwoItem"></p></td>
        </tr>
  </table>



<input type="button" class="button" value="Try" onClick="TryButton();">

<script>

ArrayList = new Array();
 ArrayList[1] = "one.one"+"one.two";
 ArrayList[2] = "two.one"+"two.two";
 ArrayList[3] = "three.one"+"three.two";
 ArrayList[4] = "four.one"+"four.two";
 document.getElementById("TotalArray").innerHTML = [ ArrayList.length-1];

function TryButton(){
ArrayId = Math.floor(Math.random()*3 + 1)
document.getElementById("PartOneItem").innerHTML = ArrayList[ArrayId][0];
document.getElementById("PartTwoItem").innerHTML = ArrayList[ArrayId][1];
document.getElementById("SelectedId").innerHTML = ArrayId;
}
</script>
</body>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you want to use the taken random values with an array as result for `xxx.one` and `xxx.two` as result.

You need to use an array of arrays and use as arrays are zero based the index zero as well. This makes a random index easier to calculate, becaus a needed addition of one for the index could be omitted.

For taking the length of the array, you need no array to wrap the value in it.

This looks right in the view, but internally it calls [`Array#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method and returns a joined string, which is just the value (as string) for a single item.

```js
function TryButton() {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    document.getElementById("PartOneItem").innerHTML = list[index][0];
    document.getElementById("PartTwoItem").innerHTML = list[index][1];
    document.getElementById("SelectedId").innerHTML = index;
 }

var list = [
        ["one.one", "one.two"],
        ["two.one", "two.two"],
        ["three.one", "three.two"],
        ["four.one", "four.two"]
    ];

document.getElementById("TotalArray").innerHTML = list.length;
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr><th>All Arrays</th><th>Selected Array</th></tr>
  <tr><td><p id="TotalArray"></p></td><td><p id="SelectedId"></p></td></tr>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tr><th>PartOne</th><th>PartTwo</th></tr>
  <tr><td><p id="PartOneItem"></p></td><td><p id="PartTwoItem"></p></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Try" onClick="TryButton();">
```